# Does Git work in Windows?

Tags: windows, git, version-control, dvcs

I work on Linux all the time and I'm clueless about Windows, not even having a Windows box. Is Git nowadays working on Windows? Or am I making problems for my Windows pals by using it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As far as I can tell [msysgit](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/) works perfectly well under Windows Vista.

This after a whole 2-month experience checking out plugins and applications for Ruby on Rails :-)

Anyway, it was a breeze to install, no problem.

Comment: I've been using msysgit on Win XP SP 2 for a while now - and had no problems with it.

Comment: We've got it running on Win XP SP3 and Win XP SP2. No issues - AND the msysgit team keeps pretty up-to-date. Was even able to get it working with Pageant to push/pull to a SSH-accessed git repo.

Comment: me too - the msysgit version has been running fine for me on Windows XP SP2. Used locally and also with remote repositories on github and heroku.

Comment: I set up a PM with msysgit and git-gui last week - no problems so far!

Comment: Note for contemporary readers: this question was asked in 2008. msysgit has been working fine for me in Windows 7 for over a year. Even gitk works.

Answer (score 6):

I have had no problems, even with the gui tools (gitk and git gui), using git from [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/).  The Cygwin people are very conscientious and have a large community to boot.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it does. Check out this [screencast at GitCasts](http://www.gitcasts.com/posts/git-on-windows).

Answer (score 2):

You should also checkout [Git-Extensions](http://code.google.com/p/gitextensions/) which adds git commands as shell extensions - works great with msysgit.

Answer (score 2):

There's a port of Tortoise for GIT, in version 0.4 so far:

- [Tortoise GIT](http://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/)

Answer (score 2):

I've heard good things about it, but a sticking point for me (and the Japanese company I work for) is lack of cross-platform Unicode filename support. It depends if that particular feature is important to you.

See [Issue 80 in the msysgit bug tracker](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/issues/detail?id=80).

See the [What DVCS support Unicode filenames?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/829682/what-dvcs-support-unicode-filenames) question I asked about this.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/q/8284306 for an update, 1.7.10 is OK with this now.

Answer (score 0):

It works, but not well.  If you Google around a bit, you'll find [the port which uses MinGW](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit).  The main problems are instability and some very Linux-like tools (gittk).  If you really need it though, you should be able to get by.

Answer (score 0):

In the case you are primary using Eclipse as your IDE, there's a fine team provider called EGit, which is pretty easy to install. Check this: http://www.eclipse.org/egit/