# Input: Applescript display dialog. Output: Python

Tags: python, encoding, applescript

I'm coding a little app that asks a question using `display dialog with default answer ""`, takes whatever the user input is (let's say die Universität), and sends it to a Python file. Python checks the spelling of the word, translates it, spits out a display dialog with the English translation.
The problem I'm having is that Applescript is not giving Python a nice encoding. Here's my code in Applescript:

```
set phrase to the text returned of (display dialog "Enter German Phrase" default answer "")
set command to "python /Users/Eli/Documents/Alias\\ Scripts/gm_en.py " & phrase
do shell script command
```

I get the input into Python. It's breaking everything, so I'm using [chardet](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/chardet) to figure out what the encoding is. It's giving me this: `{'confidence': 0.7696762680042672, 'encoding': 'ISO-8859-2'}`
Not only is this pretty innacurrate, it's an encoding I can find very little about online. Trying to convert with `decode('iso-8859-2')` gives very strange symbols.

Any ideas?

Comment: Use [UTF8](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2065/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10003093-CH1-SECTION3).

Comment: `UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 9: ordinal not in range(128)`

Comment: Python 2's `str` vs `unicode` division is a PITA. [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27425797/2298645) for how to read and write stdin/stdout as UTF8, [and here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14028665/2298645) for how to read argv likewise. Oh, and while you're at it, you also must use `quoted form of phrase` on line 2 of your AppleScript, otherwise your shell script is going to explode the moment the phrase contains spaces or other 'special' shell characters.