# translation gives strange characters even with gettext.bind_textdomain_codeset("fr", "iso-8859-1")

Tags: python, gettext

I'm translating my Python application to french. I generated `.po` file but I have a problem that the french characters are displayed incorrectly.

Example:

`exécution` appears `exÚcution`

PS:I'm using `gettext` for translation.

even when I use chcp 1252 it doesn't work.. I'm using Pydev and when I tried to print my data to Pydev console it worked but it's not what I want : that's the way I add my handlers to the logger may be that's the problem :

```
if givesFileName:
        if FileName is None:
            print('Please specify an output Text File Name')
            # Exit with error
            sys.exit()
        #create file handler
        fh = logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler(FileName, mode="w",encoding="utf-8")
        fh.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        logger.addHandler(fh) 
else:
        #create console handler
        ch = logging.StreamHandler()
        ch.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        logger.addHandler(ch)"
```

Comment: Most likely your file is not encoded as ISO-8859-1 then. Can you show us a hex dump or Python `repr()` output of some of the `.po` file lines?

Comment: msgid ""
msgstr ""
"Last-Translator: <EMAIL@ADDRESS>\n"
"Language-Team: French\n"
"MIME-Version: 1.0\n"
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1\n"
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: utf-8\n"
"Plural-Forms: nplurals=2; plural=(n > 1);\n"

#: main.py:183
msgid ""
"\n"
"    **Application **  \n"
msgstr "\n    **Application **  \n"

#: main.py:184
msgid " Start:  Function Name = Aggreg  : \n"
msgstr " Début: Exècution de la fonction Aggrég  : \n"

#: main.py:185
msgid " Retained Parametres :   \n"
msgstr " Les Paramètres retenus sont :   \n"

Comment: Ah, no, your data is being **encoded** wrong again. How are you outputting your translated data?

Comment: logging.info(_("my data"))

Answer (score 0):

Your data is being *decoded* to the [IBM-850 codec](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_850), not Latin 1:

```
>>> print u'exécution'.encode('latin1').decode('ibm850')
exÚcution
```

This means your data is correctly read from the file, but **on output** your data is encoded to an incorrect codepage.

Comment: Thanks for the answer so what should I do to fix that?

Comment: @user3328690: That depends on how your program outputs text. You'll need to provide us information about this. Is your app a web application? Desktop app? Console app? That's not clear here.

Comment: my application is a console application and it outputs data:logging.info(_("my data"))

Comment: @user3328690: Is this on the Windows console?

Comment: So your Windows console is misconfigured. Python is told to use the Latin 1 codec when writing to the console, but the console is then displaying the data written to the console using the IBM 850 codec.

Comment: What happens when you run `chcp` in the console? What codec does Windows report it is using?

Comment: it prints Active page code : 850 in fact I should tell you that my output depends on the user if he specifies a file I add to the logger  a file handler if he doesn't specify a file I add a console handler when I try to print the output data to the file I get this error :UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 18: ordinal not in range(128) and when I print it to console it's displayed incorrectly .. Thanks for your answers

Comment: @user3328690: Logging to a file assumes that you are encoding Unicode  strings yourself, or are using a `io.open()` file object that encodes Unicode for you.

Comment: @user3328690: Your incorrect output on the *console* means your console appears to be misconfigured. Python thinks it needs to encode to Latin 1, but it *should* encode to IBM850 instead. You can use `chcp 1252` in the console to fix this for now, I think.

Comment: even chcp 1252 didn't fix that :-(

Comment: @user3328690: I see another post from someone with the same issue: [Python, windows console and encodings (cp 850 vs cp1252)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9226516)