# How print non-latin letters?

Tags: python, python-2.7, character-encoding

I have a simple script parse_dict_pl.py:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

f = open('polish.txt','r')
print "Polish letters: ęóąśłżźćń"
for l in f:
        print l
```

File polish.txt contains polish letters: `ęóąśłżźćń`
I run script from windows command line as follows:

```
python parse_dict_pl.py
```

and the result is:

```
Polish letters: ─Ö├│─à┼¢┼é┼╝┼║─ç┼ä
─Ö├│─à┼¢┼é┼╝┼║─ç┼ä
```

How can I properly print polish letters hardcoded in the script and loaded from file?

Pawel

Comment: I ran the print statement in a linux environment and it prints out the letters correctly. peraps try to make sure that it is of type `str`? it might also just be the way that windows cmd displays non-latin chars, but I am not sure

Comment: which os and version ?

Comment: have these fonts installed on your system? in windows terminal even they've installed there are always problems, which i've faced in case of azerbaijani, turkish and russian texts. but in my linux (ubuntu 12.04), without any configuartion, nicely prints polish, persian (arabic scripts).
`>>> print "Polish letters: ęóąśłżźćń" => Polish letters: ęóąśłżźćń`
>>> print "که حتا تویه این شرایطم پریودی<=" که حتا تویه این شرایطم پریودی

Comment: OS: Windows 7 Enterprise, SP1

Comment: When I run this script from CygWin, I can see letters hardcoded in script properly, but those loaded from file are still invalid. I've noticed, that len(l) equals 18. So if I define variable a = 'ą' and modify loop for as follows: for l in f:
    for i in range(len(l)):
        print a == l[i] i get all false...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python, windows console and encodings (cp 850 vs cp1252)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9226516/python-windows-console-and-encodings-cp-850-vs-cp1252)

Answer (score 0):

TRY:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from unidecode import unidecode

text = u'ęóąśłżźćń'
result = ''

for i in text:
   try:
     result += i.encode('1252').decode('1252')
   except (UnicodeEncodeError, UnicodeDecodeError):
    result += unidecode(i)

print result
```

It's producing the output:

```
eóaslzzcn
```

You have to install `unidecode` library.
Get it from [library reference](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/text-unidecode)
I've taken the polish letters within a variable,you can try it according to your need. Hope it'll help you