# Passing a Hebrew file name as command line argument in Windows

Tags: python, unicode, command-line-arguments, hebrew

I have a small Python program. I use the the Windows registry to enable the opening of files using the right-click context menu. My registry entry:

> C:\Users\me\projects\mynotepad\notepad.exe "%1"

When I try and open a file with a Hebrew name using my right-click context menu, I get the file name as question marks, and I get an exception while trying to get the file size.

Here is my code:

```
file_name = sys.argv[1]
file_size = os.path.getsize(unicode(file_name))
```

I have tried this:

```
file_name = sys.argv[1].decode("cp1255").encode('utf-8')
file_size = os.path.getsize(unicode(file_name))
```

But it didn't work.

Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out it's a problem. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/846850/read-unicode-characters-from-command-line-arguments-in-python-2-x-on-windows) for the solution. You need to resort to Windows API to get the arguments.