# python2.7 utf-8 input through command line in Windows7

Tags: python, windows-7, python-2.7, utf-8, command-line-arguments

I'm a newbie, and I'm sure a similar question has been asked in the past, but I am having trouble finding/understanding an answer. Thank you in advance for being patient with me!

So I'm trying to write a script to read lines in a utf-8 encoded input file, compare portions of it to an optional command line argument passed in by the user, and if there's a match, to do some stuff to that line before printing it to an output file. I'm using `codecs` to open the files.

I'm using the `argparse` module to parse command line arguments right now. The lines in the file can be in all sorts of languages, hence the command line argument needs to also be utf-8.

**For example:**

A line from the file might look like this:

`разъедают             {. r ax z . j je . d ax1 . ju t .}`

The script should be called from the command line with something like this:

`>python myscript.py mytextfile.txt -grapheme ъ`

Here's the part of my code that is supposed to do the processing. In this case, `orth` is some Cyrillic text and `grapheme` is a Cyrillic character.

```
def process_orth(orth, grapheme):
    grapheme = grapheme.decode(sys.stdin.encoding).encode('utf-8')
    if (grapheme in orth):
        print 'success, your grapheme was: ' + grapheme.encode('utf-8')
        return True
    else:
        print 'failure, your grapheme was: ' + grapheme.encode('utf-8')
        return False
```

Unfortunately, even though the grapheme is definitely there, the function returns false and prints a question mark instead of the grapheme:

`failure, your grapheme was: ?`

I've tried adding the following at the start of `process_orth()` as per the recommendation of some other post I read, but it didn't seem to work:

`grapheme.decode(sys.stdin.encoding).encode('utf-8')`

**So my question is...**

How do I pass utf-8 strings through the command line into a python script? Also, are there any extra quirks with this on Windows7 (and does having cygwin installed change anything)?

Comment: `print repr(orth)` gives me `u'\u0440\u0430\u0437\u044a\u0435\u0434\u0430\u044e\u0442'`, and `print repr(grapheme)` gives me `'?'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are opening the input file using `codecs.open()` then you have unicode data, *not* encoded data. You would want to just decode `grapheme`, not encode it again to UTF-8:

```
grapheme = grapheme.decode(sys.stdin.encoding)
if grapheme in orth:
    print u'success, your grapheme was: ' + grapheme
    return True
```

Note that we *print* unicode as well; normally `print` will ensure that Unicode values are encoded again for your current codepage. This can *still* fail as Windows console printing is notoriously difficult, see http://wiki.python.org/moin/PrintFails.

Unfortunately, `sys.argv` on Windows can apparently end up garbled, as Python uses a non-unicode aware system call. See [Read Unicode characters from command-line arguments in Python 2.x on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/846850/read-unicode-characters-from-command-line-arguments-in-python-2-x-on-windows) for a unicode-aware alternative.

I see no reason for `argparse` to have any problems with Unicode input, but if it does, you can always take the unicode output from `win32_unicode_argv()` and encode it to UTF-8 before passing it to `argparse`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I just tried that (just having decode), but it didn't change anything except that `print repr(grapheme)` now gives me `u'?'`

Comment: @KaleidoEscape: That is an ascii question mark; either that was literally what was passed in or you used `.decode(sys.stdin.encoding, 'replace')` to ignore unknown characters. What does `repr(sys.argv)` tell you Windows passed in? What does `print sys.stdin.encoding` tell you is the expected codec?

Comment: I didn't use `.decode(sys.stdin.encoding, 'replace')`, at least consciously, heh. I am using the `argparse` module, maybe it does this? `'repr(sys.argv)` tells me `['myscript.py', 'test.txt', '-graph', '?']` and `print sys.stdin.encoding` says `cp437` (but of course I did not type a question mark when running the script, I typed ъ).

Comment: @KaleidoEscape: Then **windows** passed in `'?'` as an argument, I'm afraid.

Comment: @KaleidoEscape: See [Read Unicode characters from command-line arguments in Python 2.x on Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/q/846850) for a work-around.