# Python sys.argv alternative, Unicode bug

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygtk

I been using `os.path.abspath(sys.argv[0])` for getting the path where my exe runs always (doesn't matter where it was executed from) but python 2.x there is a problem with sys.argv http://bugs.python.org/issue2128 with unicode trying to use the script path for glade (PYGTK) file

```
self.gladeloc = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(sys.argv[0])),"file.glade")
print self.gladeloc #prints fine C:\Users\фдсфгс\Desktop\ using idle console
self.builder.add_from_file(self.gladeloc) #prints C:\Users\пїЅпїЅпїЅ\Desktop\
```

I get the following error  is there alternative for getting exe location on disk (doesnt matter where opened) i have searched other questions and it seems there is no alternative without 2 problems

1 get files location even if executed from different place

2 unicode/utf-8 support pygtk doesn't support python 3 (fixed sys.argv) so I can't just upgrade

Comment: The bug report includes a work-around.

Comment: Actually, what does `repr(self.gladeloc)` print? This looks to me do be a **different** issue.

Comment: @MartijnPieters i wasn't able to do that there is an exception but my answer seems to make it work

Answer (score 0):

Found this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/846931) It will change the sys.argv function to return unicode for py2.x. But it seems to me that it works differently than original sys.argv atleast for Idle console it showed path of `python.exe` for cmd console it showed correct `file.py` but I have found I think a better solution doesn't edit the sys.argv and idle console shows the right `file.py` unicode type `os.path.abspath(sys.argv[0].decode('mbcs'))` feedback on this will be great maybe I'm missing something? I will try do more testing and update if its not working as it should