# python: batch string en- / decoding

Tags: python, batch-file, decode, encode

i have following problem:

i wrote a python script and it needs inputparameters to run... but if the parameters include one of our german "umlaute" like äüö or ß the script stops with following error:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xfc in position
>   8: ordinal not in range(128)

and if i start the script with a batchfile, the "umlaute" are replaced with random chars like ?, some other variation of the ö....

pls help me.. thx :)

part of the code:

```
...
if batch_exe:
    try:
        aIndex = sys.argv.index("-a")
                buchungsart_regEx = sys.argv[aIndex+1]
        except:
                buchungsart_regEx = ""
else:
    ...
select_stmt = select_stmt + " AND REGEXP_LIKE (BUCHUNGSART, " + "'" + buchungsart_regEx + "')" 
...
db_list = sde_conn.execute(select_stmt) 
...
```

and the cmdinput is something like:

```
python C:\...\Script.py -i ..... -a äöüß
```

Comment: Change line 4 in your code

Comment: @jeb Wait...what am I not seeing here?

Comment: Post you code, so that we can see the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/846931/1686094

You can use his     `sys.argv = win32_unicode_argv()`

And maybe you can then encode your `sys.argv` with `utf-8` for future use.

Comment: workes great if i manually insert my command! thx!
but at the end i wanna use a batchfile to start the script and this isnt working yet... probably because a wrong string is created in the batchfile already..

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding the type of encoding at the top of your script:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```