# Python (2.7) and reading Unicode argvs from the Windows command line

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, unicode, character-encoding

I have been following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/846931/145400) on how enable Python (2.7) to correctly receive file names from the Windows command line that have names such as **'canção.pdf'**, **'조선.pdf'** or **'मान.pdf'**.

My bat file (which is in *shell:sendto*) is as follows (as advised [here](https://gehrcke.de/2014/02/python-2-on-windows-how-to-read-command-line-arguments-containing-unicode-code-points/)):

```
@echo off
@chcp 65001 > nul
@set PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8
python "D:\Dropbox\Python\print_file_name.py" %1
pause
```

My python script at moment just tries to prints these file names:

```
sys.argv = win32_unicode_argv()
file_name = sys.argv[1].encode(sys.stdout.encoding)
print file_name
```

*win32_unicode_argv()* is a method described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/846931/145400).

Even thou I am able to print **'canção.pdf'** correctly, I'm still not able to print either **'조선.pdf'** or **'मान.pdf'**. Any advice on how to tackle this issue?

Comment: [`win32_unicode_argv()` from @Craig McQueen's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/846931/145400) looks correct (and it uses the right approach `CommandLineToArgvW`). The bat-file with `chcp 65001` and `PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8` try to fix the Unicode output to the Windows console (you need to set a font that can show the characters you are interested in). The most successful approach that I know is: `print(unicode_text)` (don't encode in your script). Use [`WriteConsoleW` if you want to print arbitrary Unicode characters to Windows console](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3259271/4279)..

Comment: ..[continued] configure the font but leave `chcp` along. Use `PYTHONIOENCODING` if you want to redirect the output to a file.

Comment: Yeah `chcp 65001` breaks a lot of apps (including Python) due to bugs in the MS C runtime. Avoid it. Printing and reading unicode from the console in Windows is a notorious problem for this reason. `WriteConsoleW` via `ctypes` is the most reliable solution if you really *must* but obviously it isn't portable.

Comment: @bobince, the problems with codepage 65001 aren't in the C runtime. They're in the console host process (conhost.exe). Its design assumes an ANSI or DBCS codepage, which for a variable encoding such as UTF-8 can lead to an unchecked encoding failure for `ReadConsoleA` (even in Windows 10 -- which I just checked with a debugger attached to conhost.exe and breakpoint on `WideCharToMultiByte`) and a misreported written count for `WriteConsoleA` (fixed in Windows 8 and 10).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file name is being received correctly. You can verify this by encoding `sys.argv[1]` as UTF-8 and writing it to a file (opened in binary mode) and then opening the file in a text editor that supports UTF-8.

The Windows command prompt is unable to display the characters correctly despite the 'chcp' command changing the codepage to UTF-8 because the terminal font does not contain those characters. The command prompt is unable to substitute characters from other fonts.

Comment: I've followed your advice and was almost successful. I've: removed `@set PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8` from my bat file; changed `full_path = sys.argv[1].encode(sys.stdout.encoding)` to `full_path = sys.argv[1].encode('utf-8')`; and added `f = open('test.txt', 'wb')` and `f.write(full_path)`. I can now print both **'canção.pdf'** and **'조선.pdf'**, but not **'मान.pdf'**. I am opening _test.txt_ with Notepad++ using UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: When you open *test.txt* with Notepad++, does it say "OEM 866" in the status bar?

Comment: I was able to open the file containing "मान.pdf" in PSPad and Notepad where it displayed correctly both times. It also displays correctly in the "Preview" panel of a Choose File dialog in Notepad++. However, Notepad++ always wants to open the file as OEM 866 and doesn't seem to have an option that says "interpret this file as UTF-8 encoding".

Comment: Disabling the "Autodetect Character Encoding" option in Notepad++ will cause the file to be opened as UTF-8 by default.

However, there is still no "Open File With Encoding" command or any way to explicitly tell Notepad++ which encoding to use when reading the file - the options under the Encoding menu only seem to affect what it does when writing the file.