# How to undo a merge in GitHub

Tags: git, github, revert

I have been working in PhpStorm on a dedicated branch, but when pushing to github, I inadvertently merged to the master branch.

How would I undo the merge both in github and locally?  The github master is used to migrate code to various servers so I need to rollback to the previous commit prior to the merge rather than create a new commit with my changes undone.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rollback a Git merge](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11722533/rollback-a-git-merge)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You need to reset the head to the commit just before your current head.

```
git reset --hard <commit_before_merge>
```

E.g. git reset --hard master^

Comment: That will reset my local branch. Is it then just a case of pushing to update github?

Comment: You can either reset or checkout the previous commit and push that to github as head.
Checkout the previous commit
`checkout master^`

Comment: But hard reset or previous commit will need force push, right? A force push overwrites public history and requires everyone who has cloned the repo to rebase their clone.

Comment: @Siddu Sorry for getting back to you so late. Yes, you have to do a force push. `git push -f`.

Answer (score 12):

To answer this more succinctly:

```sh
git checkout master
git reset --hard <commit_before_merge>
git push -f
```