# Revert everything that I have done which not pushed yet

Tags: git, merge, version-control, revert

I'm looking for revert everything which not pushed into the remote branch. I have used `git revert -m 1 <merge commit hash>` as in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11722533/rollback-a-git-merge/29110174) question on StackOverflow but it is only reverting one commit which I'm not expecting. In my project I have,
**One Merge

One Merge commit

Two other commits**

I want to revert all by using some method. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+undo+merge

Comment: @phd you maybe got wrong. I want to revert everything which I have done before last push. Not to revert only the merge

Comment: The answer is the same `git reset --hard`.

Comment: but the question is diffrent noh?

Comment: A little bit. Not much.

Comment: lets assume someone wants to know how to revoke all his actions before last push. Then the person will search like that not "I wan't to revoke my merge" thats the thing I'm saying this is diffrent. Its not a problem for me its commiunity matter. anyway thank you for the feedback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all list the last 5 commits let's say and get the hash of the last commit that you want to keep:

```
git log -n5
```

Then do a hard reset to that commit:

```
git reset --hard <hash-of-last-commit-to-keep>
```

NOTE! This method will destroy the commits you don't want to keep, it won't create revert commits.