# git, msysgit, accents, utf-8, the definitive answers

Tags: git, utf-8, msysgit

I've read in some places that there are problems with git (or just msysgit?) and character encoding - I *believe* it's only a problem in file names.

What I'd like is some 'definitive' (or at least authoritative) information about:

1. What exactly are the 'problems'? (The symptoms)
2. What are the causes? (Briefly)
3. In what scenarios is this a show stopper?
4. Is there any resolution in sight, or failing that any workarounds?

I hope this question isn't too vague, I think it would be good to have all of this information in one place to be able to point people to it...

Comment: UTF-8 is commingfor msysgit. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Update Oct. 2023: with Git 2.43 (Q4 2023), the display width table for unicode characters has been updated for Unicode 15.1

See [commit 872976c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/872976c37ef6314d0480e8487a97ad5910d31148) (25 Sep 2023) by [Beat Bolli (`bbolli`)](https://github.com/bbolli).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 64b2419](https://github.com/git/git/commit/64b2419cccdc8b104f3d31981d6623e1829f6a23), 04 Oct 2023)</sup>

> ### [`unicode`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/872976c37ef6314d0480e8487a97ad5910d31148): update the width tables to Unicode 15.1
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Beat Bolli</sup>

> Unicode 15.1 has been [announced on 2023-09-12](http://blog.unicode.org/2023/09/announcing-unicode-standard-version-151.html), so update the character width tables to the new version.

---

Update Apr. 2023: with Git 2.41 (Q2 2023), the Unicode character width table (used for output alignment) has been updated.

See [commit b10cbda](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b10cbdac4c4454654f1e6f5fe81e1a20a1241858) (30 Mar 2023) by [Beat Bolli (`bbolli`)](https://github.com/bbolli).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 5ae4bd1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5ae4bd14be31361df34594d1c4be2c89e875f068), 31 Mar 2023)</sup>

> ### [`unicode`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b10cbdac4c4454654f1e6f5fe81e1a20a1241858): update the width tables to Unicode 15
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Beat Bolli</sup>

> Unicode version 15 was [released in September 2022](http://blog.unicode.org/2022/09/announcing-unicode-standard-version-150.html), and we have so far neglected to update our width tables.
> Do this now.

---

Update Oct. 2021: With Git 2.34 (Q4 2021), the Unicode character width table (used for output alignment) has been updated.

See [commit 187fc8b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/187fc8b8b6e7a2b65f7c74cfaa8aa6bad36a18b2) (17 Sep 2021) by [Carlo Marcelo Arenas Belón (`carenas`)](https://github.com/carenas).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 3d875f9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3d875f96f1974ccd9f5f25eede974b58aeb93b5e), 28 Sep 2021)</sup>

> ### [`unicode`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/187fc8b8b6e7a2b65f7c74cfaa8aa6bad36a18b2): update the width tables to **[Unicode 14](https://home.unicode.org/announcing-the-unicode-standard-version-14-0/)**

Update Feb. 2017 (Git 2.12): The character width table has been updated to match **Unicode 9.0**.
The [`update_unicode.sh`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/f3eb54920eff356a30df144d50b45a5581e5eb13/contrib/update-unicode/update_unicode.sh) is [moved it into `contrib/update-unicode`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f3eb54920eff356a30df144d50b45a5581e5eb13): see [its README](https://github.com/git/git/blob/f3eb54920eff356a30df144d50b45a5581e5eb13/contrib/update-unicode/README).

Update August 2014 (git 2.1): [commit a67c821](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a67c821dedf04683d65f2909c193617ca227cc02) ([Torsten Bögershausen (tboegi)](https://github.com/tboegi)) adds support for Unicode 7.0.

Update April 2014: [commit d813ab9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d813ab970db8b57b70bdd1b7e5feddec1c3fd84e) ([Torsten Bögershausen (tboegi)](https://github.com/tboegi)) adds support for Unicode 6.3
(git 1.9.2):

> **Unicode 6.3 defines more code points as combining or accents**.
> For example, the character "`ö`" could be expressed as an "`o`" followed by `U+0308 COMBINING DIARESIS` (aka umlaut, double-dot-above).
> We should consider that such a sequence of two codepoints occupies one display column for the alignment purposes, and for that, [**`git_wcwidth()`**](https://github.com/git/git/blob/d813ab970db8b57b70bdd1b7e5feddec1c3fd84e/utf8.c#L79-L86) should return 0 for them.
>
> Affected codepoints are:
>
> ```
> U+0358..U+035C
> U+0487
> U+05A2, U+05BA, U+05C5, U+05C7
> U+0604, U+0616..U+061A, U+0659..U+065F
> ```
>
> Earlier unicode standards had defined these as "reserved".
>
> Only the range `0..U+07FF` has been checked to see which codepoints need to be marked as 0-width while preparing for this commit; more updates may be needed.

---

Update April 2012: Unicode support is released in version 1.7.10. See [this page](https://github.com/kblees/git/wiki) for notes and settings you should set.

Namely:

```
git config [--global] core.quotepath off
git config [--global] i18n.logoutputencoding utf8
git config [--global] i18n.commitencoding utf8
git config [--global] --unset svn.pathnameencoding
```

The [`recodetree check`](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/blob/devel/bin/recodetree) command scans the entire history of a git repository and prints all non-ASCII file names. If the output is empty, no migration is necessary.

---

Update February 2012: patches for UTF-8 supports are comming in branch 'devel' of [msysgit repo on GitHub](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/commits/devel), including [Update less settings for UTF-8](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/commit/75a84f0c6863602a987dbc41cc969c67f9facfed) .

The Git for Windows Google+ page mentions:

> Karsten Blees' UTF-8 patches for Git for Windows has now been merged to '`devel`'.
> This means the upcoming release will support Unicode filenames!

---

May 2011

I believe the [msysgit issue 80](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/issues/detail?id=80) has the latest on that bug.
Also described in [issue 376](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/issues/detail?id=376).

For example:

> This is what happens:
>
> 1. git on Windows operates on file names and treats them essentially as byte streams.
>    In your case, the streams happen to be UTF8 encoded text.
> 2. git on Windows asks the runtime to create a file, and passes it the byte stream.
> 3. Since internally on Windows everything is Unicode, the runtime converts the byte
>    stream to UTF16 using the currently set locale (aka "codepage").
>    That is, it effectively interprets the byte stream as CP949 (Korean) encoded text.
>    Apparently, some of the UTF8 byte sequences are invalid CP949 sequences, and the conversion fails ("Invalid argument"); or if the UTF8 sequences happen to be correct CP949 sequences, the result is (most likely) a different character.

The true fix <del>should be on MingW though</del>:

> It occurs to me that one solution would be this: solve it at the GCC C run-time
> library level.
> That is, for the mingw GCC run-time library on Windows, make it possible via build-time options to be in a mode where the command-line parameters (passed to `main()`) and file I/O functions use the underlying Windows Unicode API calls, and translate to/from UTF-8 encoding in C's standard function APIs that use byte-strings.
> That would "just work" for git perhaps, and could be useful for other Linux-originated open source projects running the Windows environment.

[ak2](https://stackoverflow.com/users/237062/ak2) comments that [MingW](http://mingw.org/) isn't the right place for this fix:

> "MinGW compilers provide access to the functionality of the Microsoft C runtime and some language-specific runtimes.
> MinGW, being Minimalist, does not, and never will, attempt to provide a POSIX runtime environment for POSIX application deployment on MS-Windows.
> If you want POSIX application deployment on this platform, please consider Cygwin instead."

There is some work in progress on a [msysgit variant to support unicode](http://repo.or.cz/w/git/mingw/4msysgit.git/shortlog/refs/heads/kb/unicode).

Comment: So in the meantime, is it XOR(Windows, git) AND accents in file names?

Comment: Note besides: those issues have been solved in Cygwin 1.7 and hence also Cygwin git: it correctly translates between UTF-8 (or any other selected character set) and Windows' UTF-16 filename encoding.

Comment: @ak2: true, but msysgit isn't based on cygwin... @Benjol: path and filename shouldn't have any special chars for the moment.

Comment: @ak2, @VonC, so if I understand correctly, this is not a problem of git+windows, but specifically msysgit+windows?

Comment: @Benjol: yes, and more specifically, MingW, the unix-layer on which msysgit is based.

Comment: @VonC No, it's not a MinGW issue. MinGW is just a GNU compiler for Windows, and that means it uses the standard Windows C runtime library (msvcrt.dll). It has no pretensions to be a POSIX compatiblity layer like Cygwin. It's up to msysGit itself to do the necessary conversions.

Comment: @ak2: interesting, although that isn't what I understood reading the issue 80.

Comment: @VonC: From the [horse's mouth](http://mingw.org): "MinGW compilers provide access to the functionality of the Microsoft C runtime and some language-specific runtimes. MinGW, being Minimalist, does not, and never will, attempt to provide a POSIX runtime environment for POSIX application deployment on MS-Windows. If you want POSIX application deployment on this platform, please consider Cygwin instead."

Comment: I still think it would be a great step forward for MinGW to use the Windows Unicode APIs, and translate to/from UTF-8. It would bypass the complexities and limitations of locale, and allow programs to be written simply for Unicode.

Comment: Shouldn't you simply remove the old updates and leave them only in the post's history, for cleaner read?