# Cyrillic names in paths when using git

Tags: git, character-encoding, push

I have a suspicion why this error happens when I am trying to push my stub rails app to github.

[image]

Does it mean that I can't use Cyrillic account names to work with git?

By the way, in Linux Ubuntu I pushed my code successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Failed to add the host to the list of known hosts
>
> Permission denied (publickey)

And the weird `%HOMEPATH%`

Sounds like either you don't have your ssh keys set correctly or git is looking for ssh keys at the wrong place. [This post](https://serverfault.com/questions/194567/how-to-i-tell-git-for-windows-where-to-find-my-private-rsa-key) may help you configure Git to find your ssh keys.

If you still have trouble [GitHub - Set Up Git](http://help.github.com/win-set-up-git/) and [GitHub - SSH issues](http://help.github.com/ssh-issues/) may help you respectively configure your ssh keys and troubleshot the publickey issue.

Comment: Why %HOMEPATH% is weird ?
My Windows account contains cyrrilic symbols. Might it lead to problrm with git ?

Comment: It might be. Windows ports of git (specifically msysgit) have historically had [long running problems](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/issues/detail?id=80) handling encoded characters. However, [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5854967/git-msysgit-accents-utf-8-the-definitive-answers) suggests that new or soon-to-be-released versions of msysgit _may_ have better unicode support.

Comment: Relevant, timely [update](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/issues/detail?id=80#c81) to the UTF8 issue linked in my previous comment: "This issue has been fixed in the source repository, and the fix will be included in the next release of Git for Windows."