# Eclipse EGit and git on command line show different status

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

In my git repository I can do git status and it tells me that everything is up to date:

```
[598] : git status
# On branch master
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

If I connect to the repository with EGit and do a synchronize in Eclipse I get:

[image]

Somehow EGit thinks that a lot of files have been removed and readded witht the same name. Since git status returns nothing to commit I expect to get an empty window here.

For completeness: This is on OSX 10.7 but I've seen the same problem on Window 7 Pro as well.

Any ideas what's going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using non 7-bit character here (the umlaut o). 
Sorry, this is known to cause trouble.

You have to recode the tree for utf8 filename. Even if you do this, this is not bug free.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5854967/git-msysgit-accents-utf-8-the-definitive-answers) for git part, and [this bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=325828) for egit part.

Comment: Isn't Java unicode-aware by default? How weird would the code have to be to break that?

Comment: @MahmoudAl-Qudsi It's the c git compatibility problem. The c git never save the file name as "string", it is just an array of bytes. This is how OS-level file operation works in unix. Java, however, use string for file name.

Comment: @BetaRide did you read the answer in the linked question? It have two link to your answer.

Comment: Yes I read the the linked question. They deal with the windows git client. The mentioned new options deal with the enconding of the commit comments and wrong path output. As for as I understand none of this is relevant here. I think the osx git client is working fine, but EGit (based on JGit) has a problem with special characters.

Comment: you have to recode it to make it compatible with egit. It is a delusional that your current repository works -- it will break as soon as you try another locale (lets say,  a russion version of windows, korean version of linux, etc...).