# git log invalid charset name

Tags: git

I use msysgit in win7,use some commands failed. For example

```
git log
```

is not invalid, responds

```
invalid charset name
```

Someone tell me edit env, i did

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-16
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-16
```

But not usefull...

Comment: Did you tried with UTF-8 and the settings mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/a/5855213/6309 ? (With the latest msysgit 1.7.10 only)

Comment: @VonC yes,i tried it already,but was not usefull too.And when i use git by filename and pathname is ok, just command failed...

Answer (score 1):

I solved it on my system by setting `LESSCHARSET=utf-8`

Answer (score 0):

I have mine set as

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

[`.exports`](http://github.com/svnpenn/dotfiles/blob/a3603e4/.exports#L9)