# How to checkout a git repo under linux with wrong charset?

Tags: windows, linux, git, character-encoding

I have a simple (but hopefully fast solvable) problem. I created a git archive under windows using the msys/tortoiseGit tools. All right. Now I copied the repo to a USB stick and walked it over to a linux machine.

Unfortunately there are files in the repo that contain German Umlauts etc (`äöüß`). Under pure windows there is no problem and I know that under pure linux there is also no problem with that.

When I now clone the repo locally the umlauts are replaced by other characters that are not displayable on my machine (results in a `?`). At the moment I am not able to reach the windows machine to modify anything. Also it should work soon as I will no more be able to access the windows machine soon.

Therefore:

- Can I (somehow) modify the archive to ensure correct character set?
- Can I avoid this situation when I create new archives?
- Can I (only using linux) clone the repo suh that it works transparently?
- [edit] How to reweite the repo such that (at least) the file names get into the right charset?

Comment: There is no such thing as pure linux unless you mean the kernel...

Comment: You know what I mean: A homogenous setup based on linux. No windows machines.

Answer (score 2):

- Aside from rewriting the archive, not that I know of.
- <s>Make sure your Windows editors use UTF-8 instead of a local codepage.</s>
  See below.
- Your Linux might ship with non-UTF-8 locales.  To a certain extent,

  ```
  LANG=de_DE.iso88591@euro
  ```

  will request that your programs read and write in the same encoding.  However, this is not a complete fix; for example Gtk+ assumes filenames are in UTF-8 regardless of the content encoding.
- The usual way to rewrite a Git repo is using `git-filter-branch`.  Here is an example I made just now that should re-encode filenames, file contents, and commit messages from ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8.

  ```
  CONVERT='iconv -fiso8859-1 -tutf-8'
  git filter-branch \
      --index-filter '
          git ls-files -z --stage |
          while read -d "" mode ref stage name; do
              [[ "$stage" = 0 || "$stage" = 1 ]] &&
              printf "0 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000\t%s\0" "$name"
              newname="$(echo "$name" | '"$CONVERT'")"
              newref="$(
                  git cat-file blob "$ref" |
                  '"$CONVERT"' |
                  git hash-object -w --stdin)"
              printf "%s %s %s\t%s\0" "$mode" "$newref" "$stage" "$newname"
          done |
          git update-index -z --index-info' \
      --msg-filter "$CONVERT" \
      $(git for-each-ref --format='%(refname)' refs/heads refs/tags)
  ```

  Be careful: I haven't tested this in the presence of merges or binary files, and it's easy to destroy a lot of history with `git-filter-branch`.  In case something goes wrong, `git` keeps backups of all positive refs (rewritten or not) in the `refs/original` namespace.

---

Just found an amazing [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5855213) by [VonC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6309): On Windows, use `msysgit`≥1.7.10, and to fix up an existing repository, there's [`recodetree`](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/blob/devel/bin/recodetree) binary (filenames only, unlike the above).

Answer (score 0):

Git stores files as binary blobs, so you cannot fix it without rewriting the whole history. It is not about modifying the repo, but modifying the files.

Comment: So, what...? I cannot use the archive and I am dammed to use windows in future with all that repos? That looks quite bad! About the rewrite: How to do that? Passible?