# Why does git rebase say "fatal: cannot convert etf8 to utf8"?

Tags: windows, git, utf-8, rebase

I am using `git` on a windows machine, and I'm trying to use it with both the cygwin terminal and Git Bash. When I try to rebase a topic branch to master, I get the following cryptic error:

```
☻~/code/project $ git rebase master
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
fatal: cannot convert from etf8 to utf8
```

What does this mean and how can I solve it? Google gives me zero results on this.

My locale is `en_US.UTF-8`, but I do not have any `LC` environment variables.

```
~ $ env | grep LC
~ $ env | grep LANG
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

This is the version I am using:

```
~ $ git --version
git version 1.7.9
```

Comment: What encodings are you using, with what locales?

Comment: @Arafangion: Good question! How do I figure out? I'm not very confident on windows. I might add that this repo is usually developed in Linux.

Comment: From your prompt, it looks like you're using Cygwin -- if so, the `LC_*` and `LANG` variables are what you need, just as on Linux.

Comment: What version of git are you using?

Comment: @VonC 1.7.9, so almost up to date

Comment: Can you show the output of `git config i18n.commitencoding`?

Comment: Also, can you show the output of `git log --pretty="%h %e" master..` from the branch that you are rebasing from?

Comment: Is it the same version for cygwin (1.7.9) and windows (could be a msysgit1.7.10 or 1.7.11). Because utf8 was supported only for 1.7.10+: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5854967/git-msysgit-accents-utf-8-the-definitive-answers/5855213#5855213

Comment: @VonC: I'm sure that's not true (that utf-8 was only supported for >1.7.10). UTF-8 has been the primary log message encoding since the beginning. If you've committed messages in other encodings you've often been on your own until support for `i18n.commitencoding` has been honoured more widely.

Comment: @CharlesBailey right, "supported" wasn't the appropriate term. I just wonder if a pre 1.7.10 version (on Cygwin) and a post 1.7.10 (msysgit on windows) might have an influence, considering a rebase has to replay commits (and their log message).

Comment: @CharlesBailey Plus, the only part of git which has that error message is [`mailinfo.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/builtin/mailinfo.c#L504-L521). Not sure how it is linked to rebase though, even if an old thread mentions that rebase was using git-am which was using mailinfo! (http://lists-archives.com/git/705623-git-mailinfo-doesn-t-stop-parsing-at-the-end-of-the-header.html)

Comment: I'm currently struggling with a Linux box w/ `1.7.2.3` that claims `fatal: cannot convert from Latin-1 to UTF-8` during rebase when trying to apply a commit with a utf8 multibyte in the commit message. Annoying.

Comment: This particular issue seems to be resolved in `1.7.10.x` at least, so meh.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have some corrupted files or messed configuration in your repository.

My google-fu didn't come up with a character encoding named `etf8`. I think it is `utf8` with one bit error (the fifth position) in the letter `u` :

- The [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_printable_characters) code of `u` is 0x75 or `0111 0101` in binary
- The [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_printable_characters) code of `e` is 0x65 or `0110 0101` in binary

This is in my sense the most probable cause for the fatal error reported by `git`.

It can probably be fixed by editing an internal file or some config value in the repo (but unfortunately I'm not comfortable with `git` internals to know where to look).