# Git and windows 7 encoding conflicts ?

Tags: git

For some reason the files I got from remote are causing some problem on my repository. 
As you can see in changes, it came with a unknown character, and in files I have this bad character I'm able to do nothing, commit, revert, accept mine or the 'others' files.

I already tried reset HARD and re pull, re clone, no success until the moment. 
I think that it's some encoding problem, but I don't know what and where configure.

Note: My repository is on bitbucket.

Someone can help me ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What's your OS's default encoding? I thing bitbucket using `utf8` to store git stuffs. If your OS in another encoding, say Chinese encoding, you will get this problem. This is a known issue [git, msysgit, accents, utf-8, the definitive answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5854967/git-msysgit-accents-utf-8-the-definitive-answers). As far as I know, the latest `git-gui` solved this issue. TortoiseGit using msysgit as underlying git messenger, which suffered from file encoding issue.

Comment: The problem is not only the exhibition of characters. It make my git don't find the files. I tried to install the git utf8 branch, but it didn't work.

Comment: Yes, the root reason why git don't recognize your files is encoding. I don't know git utf8 branch. You can try the latest version of msysgit. http://msysgit.github.com/

Comment: I don't think the problem is with git. I have other 8 machines working with the same project, and the problem just happens on mine.

Comment: Do your other 8 machines using the same OS as your working machine? I used to have this issue, cause my repository is in a Ubuntu machine, and I am working on Windows7. Ubuntu using `utf8` as system encoding, so the file name in repository is encoded with `utf8`. My windows using `GBK` (a Chinese charset), so no matter I pull/push from/to repository, file name is in a mess.

Comment: I have XP, Windows Xp, Windows Vista, Windows 7 (32 and 64).
I don't know I removed everything related to git from my machine, re install everything. Now the problem seems fixed. I'll wait some day to be certain of it.