# Git and file content (text) encoding (utf8)

Tags: git, encoding, utf-8

## **My problem**

I'm using Git to keep track of my files and to move them between two computers.
The one I work on which is on Windows 8, and the one where I compile which is under Centos 6.

I used to work with Windows XP and Bitbucket, but I recently moved to Windows 8 and Deveo.

My problem is:
Let's figure out I have a file called "/example.sql" which contains:
"Categoría"
(Without the quotes).

Once committed and pushed, I look for the file on Deveo, which actually looks as it should: Categoría.

However, once I "git clone" or "git pull" it, it's got converted to:
"CategorÃ­a"

That is really inconvenient, as the file is to be imported to MySQL as UTF8.

### **What I've checked for**

I code in Notepad++ and I've made sure it saves the files as "UTF8 without BOM".
On Centos I've checked for the file encoding with "file -bi example.sql", which reports
text/x-c; charset=utf-8

## **My Question**

What may have happend? Is it a Deveo problem? I did not have it when working on Bitbucket and Win XP
How may I solve it?

Thank you!

Comment: You should have a look at this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5854967/git-msysgit-accents-utf-8-the-definitive-answers

Comment: @MKAI: that question is about Unicode paths, not contents

Comment: My problem is not with the paths, the file is correctly named, pulled, etc. The problem is its content (text)

Comment: Which computer are you getting the error on?  It's possible that the file contents are correct (because if the file contains UTF-8 Categoría it will show up as CategorÃa if your text editor thinks it's Latin-1) and it's just a problem with your text editor.  Git normally treats files as binary blobs so *content* encoding should be a non-issue.

Comment: If that was the case, importing the file to MySQL should work and it should later on be displayed as í. Instead, those characters are shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wild guess: You log into your Centos box using Putty. You configured your Putty to display output as something else then utf-8. - Hence the file contains the correct string it is only displayed wrong by putty.

You can verify by something like `hexdump -C example.sql`.

Comment: Yeah, well indeed I was aware I was using putty with non utf-8 enconding. The problem came down to be of MySQL not importing the file as it should. Sorry