# git & cyrillic chars

Tags: windows, git

I installed the git on Windows 7:

```
$ git --version
git version 1.9.0.msysgit.0
```

I read the *Pro Git* [russian translate](http://cloud.github.com/downloads/GArik/progit/progit.ru.pdf) and try use it. I have a problem with cyrillic chars:

[image]

How can I fix it?

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5854967/git-msysgit-accents-utf-8-the-definitive-answers).