# GIT: does not handle filenames which contain unicode char(e.g. chinese/korean)

Tags: windows, git, git-svn, msysgit, unicode-string

Issues:

- Using ls in GIT shows all unicode in filenames as '?' (i.e. ???.mp3).
- When using git add -A the following error is returned: "fatal: unable to stat 'example/???.mp3': no such file or directory"

Is there a solution to this?

Thanks.

Comment: What operating system and which git is this on? On windows and using msysgit I have the same issue as well.

Comment: @prusswan: The fact that the OP mentioned using `ls` "in GIT" pretty well implies windows/msysgit.

Comment: Yeah, I am using windows. MINGW32.

Comment: when did `ls` become a command in windows? but I digress

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/830016/60075

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/5854967/11343

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Msysgit doesn't have support for non-ASCII characters in filenames. See its [issue  80](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/issues/detail?id=80) for details.

Consider using Cygwin's git package instead, which does have full UTF-8 support.

Comment: Just to emphasise this - since 1.7.10, msysGit DOES support Unicode filenames.

Answer (score 9):

As of [MSysGit](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/downloads/list) 1.7.10 (the latest version at this time), Unicode is correctly supported on Windows, at the condition you [tweak some settings](https://github.com/kblees/git/wiki#wiki-Settings) and use a truetype font in the console.

See explanations [here](https://github.com/kblees/git/wiki), including how to deal with previous repositories.

Answer (score 0):

Git for Windows now uses Unicode for filenames.

[Edit: s/not/now/.. sic :( ]